# Prestashop - UpdateQty doesn't work on my hosting server

Tags: module, prestashop, combinations, prestashop-1.6

Everything was nice on my local server, but when I have put my module into my hosting server, updateQty method don't update my cart and don't add new product to it.

My portion of code I use :

```
    /*
     * Add one product attribute to the cart
     * @param  integer $quantity quantity wanted
     * @param  integer $idProduct product id
     * @param  integer $idProductAttribute product attribute id
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public function initSelcombino($quantity, $idProduct, $idProductAttribute)
    {
        $cart = $this->context->cart;
        $cart->updateQty(
            (int)$quantity,
            (int)$idProduct,
            (int)$idProductAttribute
        );
        $cart->update();
        return true;
    }
```

For information, I am developing a module to add a list of product attributes to the cart.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what is happening ? Do you have any error ? Did you debug your code to see if `updateQty()` is called ?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre updateQty() is called and I have no error

Comment: Are you running the same PHP version in your local server than the production server?

Comment: try without `$cart->update();`, it's not necessary after `updateQty`

Comment: @Rufein i use the same php version 5.6.12

Comment: @UnLoCo i tried without $cart->update(). the problem persist